# Customer Portal user linking from chatter post email to portal not working

Tags: community, chatter, customer-community

When we @mention a `Customer Portal User` in `Chatter` they receive an email message.

When they click on the link in the message it sends them to a URL like:

```
https://portal.example.com/s/detail/a1N4J000000RtlEUAS
```

But this opens a page which gives an error:

> Looks like there's a problem.
> This record isn't supported. See your administrator for help.

1. Is it possible to support @mentioning customer users in chatter like this?
2. If so, how do we make it work?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318811&type=1

Comment: That fixed it!!

Comment: @identigral you are my personal hero!